# Is there anything to gain by installing a second, non-identical video card in a PCIe x4 slot?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, pci-express

I'm in the position of trying to get the most out of the hardware I can afford; pursuant to that, I have an AMD Fx8350 with 32 GB RAM installed, a Gigabyte ATX motherboard that has two full length PCIe slots (and three of the short x1 slots, but two are covered by the video card, plus two legacy IDE slots irrelevant to this question).  I don't have the exact motherboard model number handy, but I'll edit it in when I'm at home.  I have an nVidia GTx 1070 installed in the PCIe x16 slot, and a free x4 slot the same length; I also have a GTx 1650 that was in the machine before a recent motherboard failure.  I have plenty of 12V power connectors, having just upgraded to a 700 W ATX power supply.

Among other things, I run BOINC distributed computing tasks on this machine when it's idle.  I'm interested in reinstalling the GTx 1650 in the x4 slot to provide additional GPU computing ability, but I'm not certain the two cards will play nice together, or that the x16 card will work well enough in the x4 slot to be worth the inevitable troubleshooting.  I don't at this time have physical space for a second monitor (and if I did, I could just connect it to one of the alternative video outputs on the GTx 1070), and since I only have two eyes and use them together, having a second monitor would be of limited utility for my use anyway.

If relevant, I'm running Kubuntu 22.04 with the current "recommended" nVidia proprietary driver.

What problems can I expect from this combination of video cards (GTx 1070 in the x16 slot and GTx 1650 in the x4 slot) and how much performance boost in GPU computing (for Einstein@Home) will I get?

Comment: Probably not? A quick googling tells me that even NVIDIA/AMD themselves have somewhat deprecated SLI/CrossFire, so unless you are talking about multiple CUDA jobs (AI/ML/blah-blah-blah) or so, you may not gain much. (Actually I'm not even sure it can do well for CUDA jobs, but it seems that at least docker allows you to choose which GPU to pass to which container(s)...)

Comment: @TomYan All graphics to the screen would come through the one in the x16 slot -- only BOINC GPU tasks would go to the secondary card (as well as the primary).

Comment: I feel like most of the 'complexity' would be in set up. The 'dissimilar GPU' set up has worked fine for over the last decade or so